# "are they" vs "aren't they" with negative statements in questions

Tags: grammaticality, tag-questions

> They never agree with us, are they?

Is this a mistake to use "are they?" instead of "aren't they?" in this sentence?

Comment: "They never agree with us, are they?" is grammatically not correct. "They never agree with us" is negative because of the presence of 'never'. The corresponding auxiliary to the verb 'agree' is do; and the correct tag question is 'do they?'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, neither "are they," nor "aren't they" are correct here.You want to say, "They never agree with us, **do** they?"

"Are they" is a phrase asking about the condition or mood of a group. For instance, one might say "They aren't very agreeable, are they?" A very similar meaning is found in the phrase, "They are very disagreeable, aren't they."